# Firebase AuthUI - Fetch additional User Information from Facebook Provider

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to get the requested information from Facebook Provider of Firebase AuthUI.

I didn't find any method to get this data. When I debug that step, I can see the requested information in the attribute "zzdd" as JSON like.

How can I get this data?

> Request birthday and gender information from user:
>
> ```
> new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder()
>   .setPermissions( Arrays.asList( "user_birthday", "user_gender" ) )
>   .build() );
> ```

---

> Fetch data from provider
>
> ```
> mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
> for( UserInfo user : mUser.getProviderData() ) { }
> ```

---

> Debbuger - user - zzdd attribute
>
> {**"birthday":"08/05/1995"**,"updated_time":"2018-05-04T21:28:53+0000",**"gender":"male"**,...}

**Firebase AuthUI Version: 3.3.1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

To get additional information by Firebase Auth you must get by SDK providers, like Facebook as code below:

> Get data from Facebook SDK on Login Success with Firebase AuthUI:
>
> ```
>                     GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
>                         AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
>                         new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
>                             @Override
>                             public void onCompleted( JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse response ) {
>                                 // Application code
>                                 try {
>                                     String birthday = jsonObject.getString( "birthday" );
>                                     String gender = jsonObject.getString( "gender" );
>                                 } catch( JSONException e ) {
>                                     e.printStackTrace();
>                                 }
>                             }
>                         } );
>                 Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
>                 parameters.putString( "fields", "birthday,gender" );
>                 request.setParameters( parameters );
>                 request.executeAsync();
> ```